# Input is available in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio

I heard that it is not possible to give input to the python program In VS Code and for this issue We should open the python file on Command Prompt.

I wonder is it really true? Because Sometimes I write code on VS Code it asks for Input but sometimes It doesn't show anything. So what is going on?

Comment: What do you really need? Debug a Python script in VS Code passing parameters?

Comment: I want to know is it really impossible for users to use input in VS Code? I am confused. If if it is not possible to use that why in some codes I write It works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official python extension of VSCode provides `Run` and `Debugging`, almost like a IDE. It's impossible not to support input.

As for the source of your misunderstanding, it may be an extension like `Code Runner`, which does not support input, just quickly help you run the code and display the output.